# Objective-C, making an NSArray of each unique character in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I've searched around and found several questions answered which were similar to this one, but not exactly the same and I have not been able to get the sample code given in those answers to work for me. I admit this could very likely be my ignorance of Objective-C getting in the way. My situation is this:

I have an NSString from a text file which contains a variety of characters. The length of the string can vary based on what is in the text file. I need to make an array giving each individual character in the string.

I've tried 5 different approaches to the problem (three of them from answers on this site) but each effort I've made to do this has resulted in a) segmentation faults I couldn't track down, b) the array remaining NULL while giving compiler warnings, or c) the array remaining NULL without compiler warnings. In case it matter's, I'm using: gcc -framework Foundation -std=c99 TestCode.m -o TestProgram

Sorry there's no specific code here because I've deleted all my failed efforts in frustration. I guess there's a reason why you shouldn't try to learn a programming language at the same time as trying to learn a new subject that you are applying the language to :)

Would anyone be so helpful as to give me a couple of snippets to work with here?

Comment: Why do you want all the characters in an array? You should show the code that gets you closest and describe the errors it shows.

Comment: so you want a NSString @"hello" to be a NSArray @[@"h", @"e", @"l", @"o"], right?

Comment: Why not just start from scratch?  Use an [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (of one-character strings) to keep track of the characters you've seen, and convert the set to an array when you're done.

Comment: The array should be of each -unique- character. You've got it right Andrey.

Comment: What about surrogate pairs, or more commonly, decomposed Unicode characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you would do it.

1. Read the contents of the file into a `NSSString`
2. Enumerate all all the characters
3. Add them to a `NSMutableSet`
4. Get `allObjects` from the set

In code that roughly translates to this

```
// 1. Get the contents of the file 
NSError *error = NULL;
NSString *textFromFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                            error:&error];
if (!textFromFile) {
    // handle error
}

// 2. Enumerate all the characters
// (I'm enumerating composed characters to be able to support for example Chinese)
NSMutableSet *characters = [NSMutableSet set];
[textFromFile enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, textFromFile.length)
                                 options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                              usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                  // 3. Add them to a mutable set
                                  [characters addObject:substring];
                              }];
// 4. Get all the objects from the set (note that it's not sorted)
NSArray *allCharacters = [characters allObjects];
```

Comment: Takes care of decomposed characters too!

Comment: Minor remark (unrelated to the problem) : `if (error)` should be `if (textFromFile == nil)` .

Comment: @MartinR why so? does it mean that error variable is not needed at all?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha `initWithContentsOfFile:...` is documented to return `nil` if it fails to read from the file or if there are encoding issues. The `error` contains information about what went wrong and is used to *actually handle the error*.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1: **Important:**  Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the method. Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the method indicates failure by directly returning nil or NO, you should always check that the return value is nil or NO before attempting to do anything with the NSError object.

Comment: Fantastic! This worked perfectly. I didn't even know NSSet existed... and as an extra bonus, I was reading the documentation on NSSet and discovered NSCountedSet. I substituted a counted set where you had a set and that solved the next problem I hadn't even started working on yet. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an NSString category that will make an NSArray of all characters in a string:

```
- (NSArray*)charactersAsArray
{
    NSMutableArray* array = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.length; i++) {
        NSRange composedCharRange = [self rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:i];
        NSString* character = [self substringWithRange:composedCharRange];
        if (character) {
            [array addObject:character];
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Or for unique characters you can use:

```
- (NSArray*)uniqueCharactersAsArray
{
    NSMutableArray* array = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.length; i++) {
        NSRange composedCharRange = [self rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:i];
        NSString* character = [self substringWithRange:composedCharRange];
        if (character && ![array containsObject:character]) {
            [array addObject:character];
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

You can use it like this...

```
NSString* myString = @"disdiefgdsaéYsué8d9ieo";
NSArray* allCharactersArray = [myString charactersAsArray];
NSArray* uniqueCharactersArray = [myString uniqueCharactersAsArray];
```

Comment: The OP wants an array of at most one of each character I think... in your case you have just broken up the string into individual characters. Also, this method risks breaking up composed characters, e.g. `é`.

Comment: your code just add ALL the characters into the array. The questioner needs an array of UNIQUE characters

Comment: I missed the fact that he was asking for unique characters. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just be aware that not every character has the length "1" (composed characters). Further reading: [Dealing with Emoji](http://sam.roon.io/dealing-with-emoji), WWDC 2011 Session 128 - Advanced Text Processing and WWDC 2012 Session 215 - Text and Linguistic Analysis.

Comment: @dreamlax I've edited my answer to now return the NSRange of the composed character at the given index. However, I wanted to point out that while testing this code I found that the composed character that you provided as an example of a composed character that would be "broken up" by my original implementation always return an NSRange with a length of 1. Anyways, you'll see the update I added above.

Comment: @David Please see my comment above.

Comment: @JeremyFox: Have a read of [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) which details about composed and decomposed characters. Although in your case you may only be getting a length of 1 for each character in the string, there is the possibility that e.g. `é` is represented as two Unicode code points, U+0065 (the plain lowercase `e`) and U+0301 (combining acute accent). In this case, `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:` will give you a range where `length > 1`. In this case, you will need to add `composedCharRange.length` to `i` or else you will read the same

Comment: character twice, because `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:` will look backwards in the string until it finds a base character. In your case, if a composed character sequence takes two indexes, it will count the character twice.

Comment: @dreamlax Hmmmm. I've read through that wikipedia page but I'm not really following how "there is the possibility that e.g. é is represented as two Unicode code points". What I don't understand is how there is a possibility that it may or may not be represented by two unicode points? In what scenarios could this be possible? A different locale maybe? I guess if I can understand this then I might be able to make more sense of this. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyFox: It's simply that there is no rule whether `é` is represented always as just U+00E9, or whether it is represented always as U+0065, U+0301. Some systems may always decompose characters (so that `é` is represented as U+0065, U+0301) and other systems may always compose characters (so that `é` is represented as U+00E9). When you *always* use one technique or the other, it is called normalising. Until strings *are* normalised, it is best to assume that they are not, and that you may encounter both U+00E9 **or** U+0065,U+0301 in a string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47204/discussion-between-dreamlax-and-jeremy-fox)